# Jquery Mobile listview disabled on voiceover

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, accessibility

Building a site with the main navigation using jQuery Mobile listview which works fine on the browsers (e.g. mobile safari) until voiceover etc is enabled whereupon the navigation is disabled because jQuery mobile adds in an aria-hidden="true"

Is there any way to stop jquery mobile adding this or a better way to allow such users to navigate my site?

example current code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="f">
  <li><a href="page1.html" role="link"><img src="image1.gif" alt="Test Image" />
  <h3>Heading</h3><p>Description</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery mobile adds:

```
<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true">
```

inside the `<li>` which I think is the cause of the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
When anchor was added to the listview, voiceover in the iphone didn't work.
As you may know, voiceover worked for alpha4, though.

Anyway, I downloaded **http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js** and changed `("aria-hidden","true")` to `("aria-hidden","false")`.
And uploaded the modified js to my server.
And the voiceover worked.

I have no idea if this change may affect other functionality.
However, so far so good.

Hope this would help.